# Receive text message asynchronously with Websocket Android Client [2]

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, websocket, push

I try to receive asynchronously text message from a websocket server (built with ASP.NET server) to an Android Client. I tried several Android websocket librairies (autobahn, android-websocket, mobile-websocket, java-websocket,... ) but the android client receives text message only after sent a message before. I would to receive message from a server (or another client) without necessary sent a text message before.

Do you know any solution or chat sample application for example ?

Thanks a lot !

(This is a second post. The first is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651695/receive-text-message-asynchronously-with-websocket-android-client))

Here is a code that I used with the autobahn lib :

```
private final WebSocketConnection mConnection = new WebSocketConnection();

private void start() {

   final String wsuri = "ws://localhost:9000";

   try {
      mConnection.connect(wsuri, new WebSocketHandler() {

         @Override
         public void onOpen() {
            mConnection.sendTextMessage("Hello, world!");
         }

         @Override
         public void onTextMessage(String payload) {
            // Here, I received message only if I have used WebSocketConnection.sendTextMessage(String) function
         }

         @Override
         public void onClose(int code, String reason) {

         }
      });
   } catch (WebSocketException e) {

      Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Please specify more details: source codes, stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

I started to work with websocket on Android too since two weeks... in my case i would like to use WSS, so, secure websockets and with self signed certificates... with all my tries the only library that worked seamlessly was [nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client) but that's just for the secure websocket case.

Anyway I put you my code here if you find it useful, I've removed some details for privacy, and if you need a simple connection you can skip the SSL part.

```
    public class SocketHandler
    {
    private final static String LOGTAG = "SocketHandler";
    private int TIMEOUT = 5000;
    private MainActivity main;
    private SocketConnector socketConnector;

    public SocketHandler(MainActivity main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public void connect() {
        socketConnector = new SocketConnector();
        socketConnector.execute();
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        socketConnector.ws.disconnect();
    }

    private class SocketConnector extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        WebSocket ws;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {   
                SSLContext context = NaiveSSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                WebSocketFactory wsf = new WebSocketFactory();
                wsf.setConnectionTimeout(TIMEOUT);
                wsf.setSSLContext(context);
                ws = wsf.createSocket("wss://" + ADDRESS);
                ws.addListener(new WSListener());
                ws.addExtension(WebSocketExtension.parse(WebSocketExtension.PERMESSAGE_DEFLATE));
                ws.connect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }       
    }

    private class WSListener extends WebSocketAdapter {

        @Override
        public void onConnected(WebSocket websocket, Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
            websocket.sendText("Hello World");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String message) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(WebSocket websocket, WebSocketException cause) {

        }
    }
}
```